# Object Oriented Design / Design Pattern scenario

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have 3 different type of shape diagrams say `Rectangle`, `Cube`, `Circle`, I want to define classes for them such that

- All classes would have Title & Color property/method,
- Circle & Rectangle would have additional method Area,
- Similarly Cube would have Volume method rather than Area method.

There is a method in which I get the reference of of 'object', following is sample method

```
public void ShapeClicked(object obj)
{
// Check the type of obj & type cast it accordingly & call the method on that object
    object obj = new Circle();

    if (obj is Circle)
    {
        Circle circleObj  = (Circle)obj;
        circleObj.GetArea();
    }
    else if (obj is Rectangle)
    {
        Rectangle rectangleObj = (Rectangle)obj;
        rectangleObj.GetArea();
    }
    else if (obj is Cube)
    {
        Cube cubeObj = (Cube)obj;
        cubeObj.GetVolume();
    }
}
```

How can I design my classes such that in 'ShapeClicked(object obj)' method

- **a)** I need not to check the type every time (should happen at run time), (This is important for me because I have many methods like 'ShapeClicked' which requires me checking the type)
- **b)** if object is of Circle then it would get only Area method, similarly for Cube object it would get only Volume method.

I can think of two approaches

- Put all the methods & properties in base class & only override required methods in derive class. Create a Factory method/class which would return the reference of Base class. With this approach my 'b' requirement does not meet
- Put only common methods/property (like color) in base class & add additional methods in derive class. This does not solve #a :(

Can anybody suggest me some solution which solves both #a & #b

Comment: Is this real code or just an arbitrary sample?  Right now your sample is fetching a numeric from the shape, but you don't show what you do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a new interface.

```
public interface IMeasurable
{
    someReturnType GetMeasure();
}

public class Circle : IMeasurable
{
    //some other methods

    public someReturnType GetMeasure() { return GetArea(); }
}

public class Cube : IMeasurable
{
    //some other methods

    public someReturnType GetMeasure() { return GetVolume(); }
}
```

**Update**

Your method would look like:

```
public void ShapeClicked(object obj)
{
    var measurable = obj as IMeasurable;
    if (measurable == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("We can only work with measurable types, which {0} is not.", obj.GetType());

    var measure = measurable.GetMeasure();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, You added'GetMeasure' method to both cicle & cube, & from there calling their respective methods.          I have lots of methods like GetVolume/GetArea some are common to both circle,cube & rest are specific to that class. how would it solve both #a & #b which I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Implement IMeasurable in the baseclasses.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511137/is-the-solution-design-optimal-c-sharp-3-tier ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You should have a base class for all shapes and have a method `ShapeClicked()` in the base class.

```
class Shape 
{
-tile
-color
ShapeClicked()
}

class PlanarShape extends Shape
{
-area
Area()
}

class SpatialShape extends Shape
{
-volume
Volume()
}

class Circle extends PlanarShape
{
ShapeClicked()
}

class Rectangle extends PlanarShape
{
ShapeClicked()
}

class Cube extends SpatialShape
{
ShapeClicked()
}
```

Then you modify the function as:

```
public void ShapeClicked(Shape obj)
{
    obj.ShapeClicked();
}
```

Via polymorphism, your call will be directed to the right class.

Comment: -1 No. It would violate the "is-a" relationship. An interface (composition) is preferred.

Comment: @jgauffin how does it vialote the is-a relationship?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Atul is working C#. You have given java code :)

Comment: I think the inheritence is appropriate, interfaces are not required.  It doesn't hurt to use them both though (Shape base class implementing the IShape interface).

Comment: if I understood correctly you put 'ShapeClicked' into the base class? 'ShapeClicked' is the consumer & there can be many function like this. Tomorrow there can be new consumers, does that mean I have to modify my base class?

Comment: @AtulSureka nu you don't. That's the point. You override the even in your derived classes without touching the base class.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511137/is-the-solution-design-optimal-c-sharp-3-tier ?

Answer (score 0):

Using base types is good when you have common behaviour you want to inherit. In your case, you really have a common way to interact with your types, but how those types *behave* is quite different.

In this case what you're really trying to do is define a common interface so you can treat your types similarly.

I would define the following:

```
public interface IShape
{
    string Title { get; }

    string Color { get; }
}

public interface I2DShape : IShape
{
    int GetArea();
}

public interface I3DShape : IShape
{
    int GetVolume();
}
```

You can then implement `I2DShape` on `Circle` and `Rectangle`, and `I3DShape` on `Cube`. Your method then can be implemented as such:

```
public void ShapeClicked(IShape shape)
{
    var shape2d = shape as I2DShape;

    if(shape2d != null)
    {
        shape2d.GetArea();
        return;
    }

    var shape3d = shape as I3DShape;

    if(shape3d != null)
    {
        shape3d.GetVolume();
    }
}
```

You still need to check whether a shape is 2D or 3D, but that's just because we've defined Area and Volume as separate things. If you wanted to define them as a singular thing, you could put that on the base interface and have all your types implement that interface.

Comment: The problem with writing conditional code based on type is extensibility.  If later on we need another type of shape we have a lot of work to do.

Comment: It depends on what other methods you are adding aside from Area and Volume.  1D (Length), 2D (Area), and 3D (Volume) seem to cover all the known diagramming dimmensions :)  I like the suggestion if it fits the broader problem you have, but you'd have to give a few more examples.

Comment: As stated, you only need to do the type check if you consider Area and Volume different things (like a sane person). If you want to treat them as the same information, you can create a method `GetAreaOrVolume` that expresses both things on the base `IShape` interface.

Comment: Thanks for your response, As I said there are lots of method like 'ShapeClicked' where I am getting 'object' as a paramter & I don't want type checking at every place. That's why I was thinking of using factory pattern. But the problem with factory pattern is that I have to put every thing in base class (override some in derive class), more importantly one can call wrong method, for e.g Shape.GetVolume() what if Shape is of type Rectangle?

Comment: `ShapeClicked` violates Open/Closed principle & Liskovs Substitution principle.

Comment: As does anything to do with `System.Linq.Expressions`, most XML tree-walking algorithms and 90% of the uses of `as` in .NET. It's not a desirable quality, but then neither is trying to force commonality where there is none.